# What's the verb form of 'deadbeat' in English?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I am looking for an idiomatic word to describe what a deadbeat does of refusing repaying. In my country, this behavior is described as 'laizhang', literally means a person refusing to repay the money he owes *intentionally*. an example of it would be:

> That deadbeat, he borrowed $1000 from someone last year and promised to repay it this year, but now he___, denying the loan he owes and trying to get away with it.

Is there a general word to say it in English? What do you call this behavior in daily life conversation? thanks.

edit: @1006a  I am looking for a word to specifically describe someone who can pay but won't in spoken English, I think that's a different request, thanks.

Comment: If he's left town to avoid paying, he's *skipped out* on a debt.

Comment: AmEng: to [weasel out](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/weasel%20out) of paying and BrEng [do a moonlight flit](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/do-a-moonlight-flit)

Comment: The answers there are primarily single-word verbs, however, and would overlap almost perfectly with answers here, e.g. *welsh, renege, shirk*.

Comment: @1006a  i see, if it has to be that you combine the two question together, would you consider migrating the other one to mine? i think my question might be more clear to understand to possible people in the future that look for similar answers, with richer in details and format.

Comment: What language is "laizhang?"

Comment: @Azor-Ahai - [Chinese](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=laizhang).  *lài zhàng* : "to renege on a debt"

Comment: *renege* is NOT used in daily life conversation. IMO, it's more likely to be a phrase, e.g., *went back on* *(what he said)* , or [*go back on*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/go-back-on)

Comment: @Mazura  if 'renege' isn't the word i am looking for, do you have any suggestion on a word that's used in daily life conversation? 'go back on' itself doesn't contain the negative connotation of the word i mentioned, thanks.

Answer (score 20):

Another alternative would be ***renege***:

> to go back on a promise or commitment
>   <sub>*from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/renege)*</sub>

This lacks the cultural slur of *welsh/welch* and is also widely used and understood.  (Many of the example sentences at the M-W definition involve promises of payment, exactly as in your proposed sentence.)

Comment: This word fits in the example sentence quite well: "but now he reneged."

Comment: I don't like this as much because "deadbeats" doesn't really go with "renege."

Answer (score 18):

A common expression here in the US is to say someone **stiffed** someone else. It works for private loans or debts or even for defaulting on a formal loan, as in

> "I had the money to repay the bank, then a gorgeous woman wanted me
>   to take her to Cancun, so I decided to stiff the bank".

The expression is also used for tacit debts, for example,

> "I was so embarrassed when my date stiffed the bartender last night"

(meaning, did not leave a tip).

Comment: Short for _stiff-arm_, an American football maneuver in which a ball-carrier pushes on the face of  a defender trying to tackle him (this is allowed by the rules). The idea is avoiding a responsibility. I have also heard people use the word _arm_ as a verb with the same meaning; _She armed us!_ when it had been arranged that she would pay.

Comment: thanks. Can 'stiffed' used to describe a refuse of repaying person-to-person?

Comment: Yes. It is commonly used for private debts.

Comment: Yes, it is, in my experience, more common person-to-person, rather than to businesses,  as in, if you loan my brother money, he will definitely stiff you.  I wouldn't, personally, use it for, say, a bank loan or utility bill, because companies usually have more resources for recovering the funds.

Comment: I agree that you would not use this on any debt where the creditor has the means to legally compel payment, so you wouldn't say that you stiffed the bank or the IRS (unless you actually got away with not paying and they give up on trying to collect).  You could stiff the mob over your gambling debts, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @Hellion You are right about the legal compulsion. I guess I was thinking about student loans, where a lot of stiffing goes on. Hence my reference to the spring break locale, where, come to think of it, a lot of stiffing goes on as well.

Comment: @JohnLawler Where'd you find that? Etymoline doesn't support it: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=stiff&allowed_in_frame=0 (genuinely curious)

Comment: A little formatting would be nice. I was half way into my second look at this question and most of the way through an answer trying different words, until yours rose above the more formatted answers... My fault of course; just saying. +1

Comment: @user239460 - *Stiffed* can be used for almost any situation that involves a discrepancy between two parties over monetary recompense. The most common phrase it's used in is probably, *stiffed [them/me] with the check.* (the bill from, e.g., a restaurant)

Comment: @Mazura  CWill said that word was used in the USA, i don't if the other English speaking country use that word as well.

Answer (score 16):

You could say he ***welched*** (or ***welshed***):

> *informal, now sometimes offensive* :  to avoid payment *—used with on*
>    <sub>*from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/welch)*</sub>

It would more commonly be used, as the definition implies, with "on", as in "he welched on the debt", but is fine alone if the debt or obligation has already been mentioned.

It is listed as "sometimes offensive" because it is a reference to "Welsh", that is, the natives or inhabitants of Wales, and their supposedly stereotypical tendency to try to avoid paying their debts.

Comment: thanks. is there a verb that's not offensive and generally used and widely accepted? i mean in spoken English.

Comment: @user239460 While the origin may be related to a derogatory cultgural reference, I don't think most modern speakers are aware of the relationship.

Comment: not commonly used, in my experience.

Comment: @Barmar I disagree. People tend to guess relationships between words, even when they're not there. For example, "niggardly" is seldom used these days because it sounds like "nigger", even though the two words are completely unrelated. People in the US probably don't think about Wales very much but I'd expect people in the UK to (correctly) guess the relationship between "welch/welsh" and the Welsh.

Comment: @DavidRicherby's right.  You might just about get away with the *c* spelling, but it's not worth the risk.

Comment: @DavidRicherby You're probably right, I was viewing this from an American perspective. I'm also old enough that when I was a kid, "Indian giver" wasn't considered racist, it was just an idiom.

Comment: We've discussed this in more depth: [Are the terms “welsh” or “welch” (as in reneging on a bet) derogatory toward the Welsh people?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/72806/48571).  The answers there may also provide sysnonyms that would work here. I don't have OED access myself but apparently ['the old nursery rhyme "Taffy was a Welshman, Taffy was a thief' ... appears in an OED citation, too, hence the coining of the verb.'](http://virtuallinguist.typepad.com/the_virtual_linguist/2012/02/the-verb-to-welch.html)

Answer (score 10):

A more formal term would be ***default***, as in:

> That deadbeat, he borrowed $1000 from someone last year and promised to repay it this year, but now he has defaulted, denying the loan he owes and trying to get away with it.

or

> ...he defaulted on the loan...

The relevant definition:

> ***[default](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/default)***
>
> VERB
>
> [NO OBJECT]
>
> 1. Fail to fulfil an obligation, especially to repay a loan or to appear in a law court.
>      *‘the dealer could repossess the goods if the customer defaulted’*
>      *‘some had defaulted on student loans’*

Comment: This was my first thought too, and it's good to describe failing to pay in general, but the OP is looking for something to specifically describe someone who *can* pay but *won't*. Defaulting on a loan usually occurs because people are unable, but not unwilling, to meet their obligations.

Comment: @Nuclear Wang  thanks, i think you speak out the words that i want to say with natural English, i shall update my question. and to this answer, never mind, i welcome and appreciate all kind of answer and comment regarding my question.

Comment: Default doesn't indicate clear *intent* of non payment or 'reneging'

Comment: @NuclearWang I do not agree that saying someone defaulted on a loan, implies that they couldn't afford it. I do agree that it doesn't imply that they could afford it, though, either. I've heard the term "strategic default" for deliberately not paying, but it's not common.

Answer (score 10):

I'd go with **shirk**. I.e. he shirked his responsibility to pay his dues.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/shirk

> 1. Avoid or neglect (a duty or responsibility)
>      ‘I do not shirk any responsibility in this matter’